# Я пишу бота на Discord.py, который выдаёт мемы, если получит какое-то слово. Как поместить отправляемое фото под функцию внутри on_message(message):

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Суть в том что при получении слова, бот отправляет мем. Так вот: как поместить блок с помощью которого отпраляется фото из директории, в функцию, чтобы потом использовать её вот так:

```
if message.content.lower().startswith('blabla'):
    send_meme1()
if message.content.lower().startswith('blablabla'):
    send_meme1()
```

Или можно сделать как-то по другому? Мне нужно чтобы отправлялся один мем при множестве сообщений в разных формах. Думаю понятно изложил мысль. Фрагмент кода, который не работает:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    help_message = [botver + '\n', 'Этот бот выдаёт разные мемы, если услышит определённые слова.', 'Просто общайтесь и ждите ответа.', 'Когда-нибудь добавлю в этого бота ИИ.\n', 'Разработчик: BlitPlay#2819']
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
# Help Operator
    if message.content.lower().startswith('!help'):
        await message.channel.send(" \n".join(help_message))
# Meme 1 Code Block Start
    async def send_meme1():
        DIR = 'memes'
        DIRR = os.path.join(DIR, '1.jpg')
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File(DIRR))
    if message.content.lower().startswith('q'):
        send_meme1()
    elif message.content.lower().startswith('Привет'):
        send_meme1()
```

Comment: Или можно сделать примерно так:
if message.content.lower().startswith("blabla", "blablabla", т.д.): ?
Я новичок в Питоне, не судите строго

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить ключевые слова в список, и затем проверять сообщение на наличие в этом списке

**Вариант 1:** Через цикл for

```
words = ['bla', 'blabla', 'blablabla']

#проверяем в цикле for
for word in words:
     if message.content.lower() == word:
        send_meme1()
```

**Вариант 2:** через одно условие (более правильный)

```
words = ['bla', 'blabla', 'blablabla']

#проверяем в цикле for
if message.content.lower() in words:
      send_meme1()
```

Comment: С этим разобрался, но вопрос - как вставить блок с помощью которого отправляется мем в одну функцию, остался открытым. Я так понимаю нужно вставлять эту функцию в @bot.command или что-то типо того.

Comment: Если у вас это отдельная функция, вы можете вставить ее внутрь асинхронной `on_message()`, python это позволяет